# How do I accept a cross-domain POST via AJAX in a rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I do not know how to write my controller to accept a post from another domain and return a text string "OK" on success?

Can someone please show an example using a Rails 3 controller and the jQuery that would exist on another domain?

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/lists",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: myData
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm hitting on the same prob here (but with ajax)... Have you really managed to use dataType jsonp with type: POST ? what is the jquery version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Lists` controller, have something like this:

```
def index
   # do your stuff

   respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => "OK".json }
   end
end
```

You'll not actually have to return the "OK" from the Rails controller. jQuery detects automatically if the request was successful and you can do anything you'd like by adding `success: some_function(data)` to the AJAX request.

Additionally, you can look at more information regarding returning data as JSON [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoGenerateJSON).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Rails controller part specifically, but it shouldn't matter. Does your data being sent require you to do a POST, or could you use a GET request? I think the cross-domain issue is more easily resolved for the latter. I've had success with POSTs cross-browser, but Firefox is usually won't quit barking about it.